Integral of $\frac{\ln(\tan(x))}{\tan(x)}$ from $\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$
I was wondering about how I would go on evaluating
$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\ln{(\tan{(x)}})}{\tan{(x)}}dx$$
I used a calculator to find it evaluates to $\frac{\pi^2}{48}$, but I'm unable to prove this result. I've tried basic integration technique and Feynman's rule of integration to no avail. Thoughts?

Which changes-of-variable have you tried?

I can imagine a calculator estimating this value as $\approx 0.2$, but from there going to $\frac{\pi^2}{48}$, how does your calculator do that? :-)

Substitute $t=\frac1{\tan^2 x}$
$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\ln{(\tan{x}})}{\tan{x}}dx=-\frac14 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1+t}dt\overset{ibp}=\frac14 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1+t)}tdt
$$
where $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1+t)}tdt =\frac{\pi^2}{12}$.

Letting $t=\cot x$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\ln (\tan x)}{\tan x} d x 
& =-\int_0^1 \frac{t \ln t}{1+t^2} d t \\
& =-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \int_0^1 t^{2 n+1} \ln t d t \\
& =-\left.\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left[\frac{d}{d a} \int_0^1 t^a d t\right]\right|_{a=2 n+1} \\
& =-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \cdot\left.\left[-\frac{1}{(a+1)^2}\right]\right|_{a=2 n +1} \\
& =\frac{1}{4} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2} \\
& =-\frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{\pi^2}{12} \\
& =-\frac{\pi}{48}
\end{aligned}
$$
